# Bug when trying to define DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE within a python script which requires it

Tags: python, linux, django, environment-variables

i'm working on a django project and I have a standalone script called runthis.py. This script handles data within a database, so it's calling a lot of django Model classes. Like from Model.models import Model. But to do this in a standalone script you have to set the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE env variable with export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=App.settings. This can easily be done in the terminal but I wanted to set it in the script itself...

Here is my code:

```
# runthis.py
import os
os.system("export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=App.settings")
from Model.models import Model # AN ERROR HAPPENS HERE
```

Here is the error I get:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
>   DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the
>   environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
>   settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Any hints? The whole idea behind this is that the runthis.py script needs to be on a cron job. I didn't know how to export env variables in a crontab -e, so I just wanted to make it convenient and put it into the .py script itself.

Any advice would be amazing, thank you.

Comment: You look into writing a [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/). "Custom management commands are especially useful for running standalone scripts or for scripts that are periodically executed from the UNIX crontab or from Windows scheduled tasks control panel."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `os.system` creates a separate subshell.  You set the environment but then it immediately disappears because the shell exits after that one command is run.  Try using [`os.environ`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ).  (I don't know enough about Django to know if this will actually work or not; you may need to actually set the environment variables before you start the Python process.)

Also, the error message suggests calling `settings.configure` as an alternative.  Did you try that?